# Tensorflow RNN accuracy and cost: NaN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I trained a RNN for some signals and their one hot encoded labels. After working through some size and shape mismatches, the network running without error. However I am getting NaN for loss and accuracy.

```
Epoch 1 completed out of 10 loss: nan
Epoch 2 completed out of 10 loss: nan
Epoch 3 completed out of 10 loss: nan
Epoch 4 completed out of 10 loss: nan
Epoch 5 completed out of 10 loss: nan
Epoch 6 completed out of 10 loss: nan
Epoch 7 completed out of 10 loss: nan
Epoch 8 completed out of 10 loss: nan
Epoch 9 completed out of 10 loss: nan
Epoch 10 completed out of 10 loss: nan
Accuracy: nan
```

Here is how I set my input data and labels-

```
"""Input signals"""
for X in range(no_tau):

    random.seed()
    tau = np.array([int(math.ceil(np.random.uniform(lorange, hirange)))])
    X= amplitude * np.exp(-t / tau)
    X = np.reshape(X, [-1, 1,1])
    #print(X)
"""Output labels"""
cn = 0
class1 = [0]
class2 = [1]
while (cn <no_tau):
    tau = np.array([int(math.ceil(np.random.uniform(lorange, hirange)))])
    if tau<500:
        label = one_hot(class1, num_labels=2)
    else:
        label = one_hot(class2, num_labels=2)
    cn = cn + 1
    print ('For tau value of', tau, 'label is', label)
```

I am feeding the data in batches like this-

```
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i = 0
            while i < no_tau:
                start = i
                end = i + batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(X[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(label[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i += batch_size
```

After running the code I either get very small cost or NaN. For accuracy I get NaN every time.
I have checked some of the related stack questions but cannot understand the problem. Please help.

My full code gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/tu-lee/9eb8bbfc81317bd3f288e207de7feb5a)

Comment: Your learning rate is too high.

Comment: I tried with small LR 1e-5 and 1e-10 ,still get NaN

Comment: There may be more problems, but you aren't setting `X` and `labels` properly

Comment: Hi @rvinas what is wrong you think? Could you please suggest?

Comment: Try to print `X` and `label` before calling `train_neural_network(x)`.

Comment: @rvinas I printed x and label before calling `train_neural_network(x)`.

`x value is: Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 1, 1), dtype=float32)`

`For tau value of [519] label is [[ 0.  1.]]`

Comment: You're only using 1 sample. That's not the reason for nan, but take that into account. Also, you're shadowing some variables.

Comment: Using one sample mean one input? So perhaps you mean increasing batch number?

Comment: And sorry I didn't understand shadowing variable :(